# PyQt: TypeError: 'Wrong base class of toplevel widget'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have created to .ui files using `QtDesigner` and I load them into two seperate windows as show below.

```
import math
import os
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import qimage2ndarray
import Astar
from PyQt6 import uic, QtCore,QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PIL import ImageQt
width = 64
height = 40
cell_width = 10
cell_height = 10
CSV_DELIMITER = ','

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('Main.ui', self)
        self.show()
        #map
        self.map = None
        self.map_frame = None
        self.way = []
# button
        self.map_image.installEventFilter(self)
        self.Create_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.creat_map)
        self.load_image_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.load_image)
        self.save_image_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.save_image)
        self.start_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.find_way)
        self.save_csv_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.save_scv)
        self.load_csv_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.load_csv)
        self.save_map_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.save_map)
        self.start_x.valueChanged.connect(self.draw_map)
        self.start_y.valueChanged.connect(self.draw_map)
        self.end_x.valueChanged.connect(self.draw_map)
        self.end_y.valueChanged.connect(self.draw_map)
        self.start_x_ = self.start_x.value()
        self.start_y_ = self.start_y.value()
        self.end_x_ = self.end_x.value()
        self.end_y_ = self.end_y.value()
        self.load_image_path = ''

    def load_image(self):
        self.load_image_path= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(filter = "(*.png *.jpg*.bmp)")[0]
        self.folder.setText(self.load_image_path)
        image = cv2.imread(self.load_image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (width, height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
        image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
        self.map = np.array(image) // 255
        self.draw_map()
 
  
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

but when i try to compile it i have the problem.

```
TypeError: ('Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class '__main__.QWidget'>, 'QDialog'))
```

I tried to change name of class to `QMainWindow` but it didn't help.

Comment: Change to QDialog instead of QWidget or QMainWindow: you must use the same type you created in Designer.